# pass enum to strong typed partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, strong-typing

I have an strong typed partial view that receives an enum:

```
@model MyEnum 
@{
   Layout = null
}
@if (Model == MyEnum.Value1) {
    //... dosomething
}
@if (Model == MyEnum.Value2) {
    //... do another thing
}
```

I can't call render partial properly like this

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("MyPartialView", MyEnum.Value2); }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than the fact that you are missing a `;` after the null layout assignment I cannot see what prevents you from doing so (*unable to repro* as I like saying):

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Here's a full working example illustrating that this should work.

Model:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Value1,
    Value2
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

`Index.cshtml` view:

```
<div>
@{ Html.RenderPartial("MyPartialView", MyEnum.Value2); }
</div>
```

`MyPartialView.cshtml` partial:

```
@model MyEnum
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@if (Model == MyEnum.Value1) {
    <div>Value 1 was selected</div>
}
@if (Model == MyEnum.Value2)
{
    <div>Value 2 was selected</div>
}
```

which as expected outputs in the resulting HTML:

```
<div>Value 2 was selected</div>
```

Comment: @darin-dimitrov curious, it doesn't work in my example because i was using RenderPartial in a layout.

Comment: @k-dev, try specifying the full path to the partial in this case: `@{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/SomeController/MyPartialView.cshtml", MyEnum.Value2); }` or try putting it in the Shared folder.